# Titlesec puts tikz drawing below the chapter's name

Tags: luatex, fancyhdr, titlesec

In an attempt to put two drawings before and after the chapter's name with the format options provided by the `titlesec` package, the second drawing goes to the line below the chapter's name. I tried to put code of the drawing inside the`[after code]` parameter, but it didn't work out.

Also, with the `fancyhdr` package I set the header and footer but they don't show in the page containing the chapter.

How can I put the second drawing in the same line after the chapter's name and make the header and footer appear in the page with the chapter? I'm compiling it with `LuaLaTeX`.

Here's a MWE of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{MyriadPro-Regular}[
        BoldFont = MyriadPro-Bold,
        ItalicFont = MyriadPro-It,
        BoldItalicFont = MyriadPro-BoldIt]

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \disablehyphenation

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage[
    hmarginratio = 1:1,
    left = 3cm,
    right = 2cm,
    top = 3cm,
    bottom = 2cm,
    headheight = 15pt
    ]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{redd}{HTML}{b24550}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{Lorem Ipsum}
    \lhead{Ipsum Lorem}
    \rfoot{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[black] (0,0) circle (2mm);
            \node at (0,0) {\color{white}\thepage};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \chead{
        \tikz \fill[rotate=45,redd] (0,0) rectangle ++(45:.14);
    }

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}% command
        [block]% shape
        {\centering\bfseries\huge}% format
        {}% label
        {0cm}% sep
        {   \raisebox{.15cm}{\tikz \fill[rotate=45,redd] (0,0) rectangle ++(45:.2);}
            \hspace{.3cm}
        }% before code
        [   %\hspace{.3cm}
            \raisebox{.15cm}{\tikz \fill[rotate=45,redd] (0,0) rectangle ++(45:.2);}
        ]% after code


\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\sloppy

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to surround the title with the decorations; the easiest way is to define an appropriate macro, to which the chapter title is passed as an argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[
  hmarginratio = 1:1,
  left = 3cm,
  right = 2cm,
  top = 3cm,
  bottom = 2cm,
  headheight = 15pt
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\setmainfont{MyriadPro-Regular}[
  BoldFont = MyriadPro-Bold,
  ItalicFont = MyriadPro-It,
  BoldItalicFont = MyriadPro-BoldIt,
]

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\disablehyphenation

\definecolor{redd}{HTML}{b24550}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Lorem Ipsum}
\fancyhead[L]{Ipsum Lorem}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[black] (0,0) circle (2mm);
  \node at (0,0) {\color{white}\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \tikz \fill[rotate=45,redd] (0,0) rectangle ++(45:.14);%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}% command
  [block]% shape
  {\centering\bfseries\huge}% format
  {}% label
  {0cm}% sep
  {\mychaptertitle}

\newcommand{\mychaptertitle}[1]{%
  \raisebox{.15cm}{\tikz \fill[rotate=45,redd] (0,0) rectangle ++(45:.2);}%
  \hspace{.3cm}%
  #1%
  \hspace{.3cm}%
  \raisebox{.15cm}{\tikz \fill[rotate=45,redd] (0,0) rectangle ++(45:.2);}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-25]

\end{document}
```

(For producing the image I didn't load `fontspec` and `polyglossia`.)

I massaged a bit your preamble, in order to separate loading of packages, settings and command definitions.

[image]

Comment: And `\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{fancy}` to show header/footer on the chapter title page (request from the OP, not mine! `:-)`)

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you very much.